# Encode OpenGL offscreen render to video using ffmpeg, OpenGL stop refreshing after a few frames?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I'm developing a android application that can render a video using OpenGL and encode the frames into a video using ffmpeg.
I'm doing the render and encode part in ndk.

First I setup a off screen OpenGL es context using EGL, then I draw the frame using OpenGL es calls.

Then, I grab the pixels using glReadPixels, and encode them into a video using ffmpeg calls.

The problem is, after about 25 frames, the OpenGL drawing calls don't work anymore. The glReadPixels call always get the same data.

I'm guessing I have lost my OpenGL context after 25 frame, but when I tried to check that by comparing the result from "eglGetCurrentContext" with the context I created, I always get "true"

Am I checking the context in the right way? And if I did lost my context, how can I switch it back?

Comment: Just throwing out random ideas: you're not calling `glReadPixels` from a different thread, right?

Comment: No, I'm not. I did create a new thread for the OpenGL calls, but all my OpenGL calls are on that thread.